# Coregister 3D Nifti Images

Tags: python, image-resizing, nifti, image-registration

I've two 3D nifti images, a Flair image of size 29x512x512, and a dwi image, of size 73x112x112, and I would like to coregister the flair image to the dwi image.
Do you know a possible way to do that?
I'm working with Python but any well explained method would be fine

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

there are loads of ways to do that:

1. using the program FSL, registration in [FLIRT](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FLIRT), works in Linux
2. using the program [SPM](https://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm) (requires matlab)
3. [Elastix](https://elastix.lumc.nl), a command-line program that also has Python bindings
4. [ANTs](http://stnava.github.io/ANTs), also command-line, with possible Python bindings (via nipype)

but there are many more. For a good overview and a very recent method (MMORF), you may want to look at [this document](https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/10101646/1/1-s2.0-S1053811920304481-main.pdfhttps://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/10101646/1/1-s2.0-S1053811920304481-main.pdf).

Comment: Also SimpleITK has Jupyter notebooks demonstrating how to use it for registration:  http://insightsoftwareconsortium.github.io/SimpleITK-Notebooks/Python_html/60_Registration_Introduction.html